# Python: I don't understand the order of a function calling a function

Tags: python, list, function, list-comprehension

I'm following the book Data Science from Scratch by Joel Grus and they decribe the following code to create an identity matrix

```
def make_matrix(num_rows, num_cols, entry_fn):
    return [[entry_fn(i, j) 
            for j in range(num_cols)]           
            for i in range(num_rows)]

def is_diagonal(i, j):
    return 1 if i == j else 0

identity_matrix = make_matrix(5, 5, is_diagonal)
```

Although I can sort of see how this create an identity matrix, I'm having difficulties exactly understanding it.

The way I see it is that we call the function `make_matrix` with arguments `5`, `5` and `is_diagonal`. At that point the code will thus go to the `is_diagonal(i, j) for j in range(5)` and so it will go to the function `is_diagonal` without having seen the outer loop `... for i in range(5)`. But if this is true, then it seems that the function `is_diagonal` will get as input variable `(0,j)`, `(1,j)`, ..., `(4,j)` and so `is_diagonal` doesn't get enough input variables (because `j` isn't defined). Could someone please explain where I'm going wrong in my train of thoughts?

Comment: Think about why `entry_fn(i, j)` doesn't get called before Python gets to `for j in range(num_cols)`. The same logic applies to why the inner list comprehension doesn't get evaluated before Python gets to `for i in range(num_rows)`.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The way I see it  now, due to cwallenpoole's answer, is that the "outer" comprehensive list (i.e. the last part of the expression) is evaluated before the "inner" comprehensive list, and this actually explains why "`entry_fn(i, j)` doesn't get called before Python gets to `for j in range(num_cols)`". The way you phrase is seems as if my logic is backwards?

Comment: Your logic seems mostly right; there are a few parts where I can't tell whether you have the idea wrong or you're just using the wrong words. Trying to correct your usage of "evaluate" would probably be more confusing than helpful, though. I will say that "comprehensive list" isn't an actual term, though; the correct term is "list comprehension", and it refers to everything from the opening bracket to the closing bracket, not just the part starting at `for`.

Comment: @user2357112 thank you! Always happy to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That type of expression [(a comprehension)](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php) is almost best of thought of in a Yoda sense: backwards it is. The last part of the expression is evaluated before the first.

This function is the equivalent of:

```
def make_matrix(num_rows, num_cols, entry_fn):
    ret = [] # you are dealing with an outer list 
    # and an outer loop
    for i in range(num_rows):
        cur = [] # and an inner list
        # And an inner loop
        for j in range(num_cols):
            curr.append(entry_fn(i,j)) # you add the result to the inner list
        # and once you're done with the inner loop, and the result to the outer list
        ret.append(cur) 
    # finally, complete the outer loop and return the result
    return ret
```

Both `i` *AND* `j` exist in the greater context of the function, even though `i` is defined after `j` in the more compressed version.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved if you at least mentioned that this was a list comprehension and provided a link to what that is, instead of simply expanding it

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer! Just to be sure: whenever we have a comprehensive list in another comprehensive list, the "outer" comprehensive list (i.e. the last part of the expression) is **always** evaluated before the "inner" comprehensive list? Or is this a special case?

Comment: I love the Yoda comparison... makes it understandable for the hobby programmer.